# POST new schema to SOLR

Tags: schema, solr

Is there any way of POSTing a new schema to Solr (eg. is there a handler for managing schema updates) instead of manually placing the new schema.xml in Solr home directory?

Comment: One thing that does work is that if you are using master/slave replication, at least your slaves can be configured to pull updated schemas in!...   A crazy hack would be to have your Solr pull JUST schema files from yet another Solr that is where you drop new schema and other files into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately [that's an open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-791) as of this writing, and there doesn't seem to be much interest to implement it.

As suggested in the comments you can work around this by setting up some external connection like WebDAV, FTP, SFTP, SCP.